# OpenCV: How to copy text from one image and super impose on another

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a image with only text(always in white color) in it and i want to copy the text from it to another image.

Below is the image with logo and image. Currently I am taking a screenshot of this text and superimposing it over another images however as you can see I get the black rectangle along with the text, how can I get rid of the black rectangle area or just copy text from black frame to image?

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
image_2_replace = cv2.imread(mask_image2)
im2r = cv2.cvtColor(image_2_replace, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

image_2_title_img = cv2.imread(image_2_title)
image_2_titl_img = cv2.cvtColor(image_2_title_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

im2r_title = cv2.resize(image_2_titl_img, (left_image_msg[2], left_image_msg[3]))

# take the coordinate of the location where i need to put the text screenshot and add it over the image.

im2r[153: 153 + 324, 
     580: 580 + 256] = im2r_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Black background gets copied as well since you paste the whole cut-out into your image:

```
im2r[153: 153 + 324, 
     580: 580 + 256] = im2r_title
```

But since your title is on a nice black background you could only copy those parts of the picture which stand out from black. Those parts of your cut-out would have an rgb code different from [0 0 0].

The implementation could look like this (i used your screenshots and some different cut-out locations):

```
im2r[153: 153 + 70,
     280: 580 + 200,
     ] = np.where(im2r_title < [100, 100, 100], im2r[153: 153 + 70,
     280: 580 + 200,
     ], im2r_title)
```

The magic gets done by `np.where(im2r_title < [100, 100, 100],...`. Here i tell numpy to only replace those pixels in the im2r picture which have "less" color than [100, 100, 100]. This means that the black/darkgrey regions wont get pasted onto your image. (entire code below the image)

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image_2_replace = cv2.imread("92K7B.png")
im2r = cv2.cvtColor(image_2_replace, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

image_2_title_img = cv2.imread("J33EF.png")
image_2_titl_img = cv2.cvtColor(image_2_title_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

im2r_title = image_2_titl_img[250:320, 200:400]
cv2.imshow("image_2_title_img",im2r_title)

# take the coordinate of the location where i need to put the text screenshot and add it over the image.
im2r[153: 153 + 70,
     280: 580 + 200,
     ] = np.where(im2r_title < [100, 100, 100], im2r[153: 153 + 70,
     280: 580 + 200,
     ], im2r_title)

cv2.imshow("image_2_title_img",im2r)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```